# How do I handle the click event of a v-menu in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I check and handle the click event of a `v-menu` in Vuetify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on: { click } }">
  <v-btn @click="(click) (exit=!exit)" icon>
    <v-icon v-if="!exit">mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
    <v-icon v-else>mdi-close</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

As you can see, if the menu is clicked the exit var is set to its opposite value and therefore the `mdi-close` icon is shown on the button. If the menu is clicked again, the event changing the exit variable will trigger again and the vertical dots will be shown.

I only posted this question to save the exact syntax for myself for later because I have been digging Vuetify docs for hours and finally figured out how to do it.

Comment: but where is exit variable declared ?

Comment: In this particular example it's simply declared in the script tag with the default value 'false'.

Comment: ok, but let's say exit= false, & when user clicks on button then exit will be true but when user will click outside of the v-menu (not on button) then menu will be hidden & exit is still true which means its not syncing. In this case this logic will fail here. Mark me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to use v-model on v-menu & watch to variable change.

HTML

```
  <v-menu
    v-model="isOpened">
  </v-menu>
```

SCRIPT

```
export default({
   watch:{
    isOpened: function(){
      // do whatever you want
    } 
  }
})
```